# Jetpack Compose has CutCornerShape API now changed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

My recent work with Jetpack Compose suddenly has errors when using CutCornerShape. It used to take DP as parameter but now looking at it, it takes a CornerSize instead and you can't just set one parameter like before, you have to give 4 different CornerSizes. Does anyone know if this is official by Android as it's quite a big change to make.

[image: image showing the issue]

Answer (score 0):

With `1.0.0-beta01` you can use:

```
CutCornerShape(8.dp) //CutCornerShape with the same size applied for all four corners.
CutCornerShape(8.dp, 8.dp, 16.dp, 8.dp)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works anymore, it used to, but now an error appears showing CutCornerShape can't take DP as a param. I've got all the CutCornerShape imports in my file too

Comment: Just tried with `import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CutCornerShape` and it works without issues

Comment: I've added an image to OP so you can see the issue

Comment: @alfietap are you using 1.0.0-beta01? I'am not able to reproduce the issue

Comment: Yes using 1.0.0-beta01. It's just strange as it worked as you described yesterday, then when I loaded up android studio today the CutCornerShape API appears to have changed itself

Comment: same problem i'm facing using RoundedCornerShape, Type mismatch.
Required:
CornerSize
Found:
Dp

Comment: which version of kotlin compiler are you using?

Comment: ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.30'
 ext.compose_version = '1.0.0-beta01'